# How do I test for an exception in minitest?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using Rails 5 with minitest.  How do I properly catch an exception being raised from invoking a controller method?  I thought

```
assert_raises
```

was the key.  However, I have this method

```
  def show
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and although I thought I'm capturing a REcordNotFoundError but writing

```
  # Simple test to verify we get the show page when we
  # invoke the page with a valid ID
  test "get show page with invalid line id" do
    invalid_line_id = -1
    assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound get line_path(invalid_line_id)
  end
```

and then running it results in a

```
# Running:

.E

Error:
LinesControllerTest#test_get_show_page_with_invalid_line_id:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Line with 'onestop_id'=-1
    app/controllers/lines_controller.rb:7:in `show'
    test/controllers/lines_controller_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:LinesControllerTest>'
```

error.  What's the right way to catch the error in my test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert_raises` expects a block - you've just called the code.

Try something like:

```
assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  get line_path(invalid_line_id)
end
```